# Reverse leaf order in dendrogram using R

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust

I have tried for several days to just flip a dendrogram so that the last gene is the first in the figure and the first the last. But even when I have managed to move leaves around the internal ordering is not the same. Here is my script:

```
cluster.hosts <- read.table("Norm_0_to1_heatmap.txt", header = TRUE, sep="", quote="/", row.names = 1)
# A table with 8 columnns and 229 rows cirresponding to gene expression 
 hosts.dist <- dist(cluster.hosts, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE, p = 2)
 hc <- hclust(hosts.dist, method = "average")
 dd <- as.dendrogram(hc)
 order.dendrogram(dd)

X11()
par(cex=0.5,font=3)
plot(dd, main="Dendrogram of Syn9 genes")
order.dd <- order.dendrogram(dd)    #the numbers in the order indicate the position of the gene in the original table
#Then I generate a vector with the opposed order to the one obtained
y <- c(206, 204, 210, 209, 213, 212, 211, 207, 208, 94, 199, 192, 195, 198, 193, 201, 203, 200, 185, 61, 191, 190, 197, 189, 188, 196, 187, 215, 214, 202, 217, 220, 219, 218, 95, 180, 179, 181, 182, 186, 178, 132, 133, 122, 66, 65, 64, 58, 91, 88, 92, 89, 62, 184, 103, 128, 127, 229, 231, 230, 148, 63, 228, 116, 134, 104, 221, 78, 20, 232, 160, 159, 225, 112, 167, 164, 166, 140, 222, 51, 149, 227, 79, 68, 90, 131, 130, 136, 135, 105, 147, 172, 150, 176, 175, 174, 177, 152, 151, 165, 137, 168, 163, 52, 146, 141, 145, 82, 81, 56, 161, 120, 144, 129, 84, 1, 173, 143, 142, 86, 85, 83, 194, 183, 111, 55, 53, 54, 224, 171, 170, 223, 169, 93, 59, 60, 123, 121, 124, 87, 125, 226, 3, 158, 47, 10, 162, 138, 139, 154, 153, 119, 118, 117, 106, 80, 45, 70, 69, 126, 205, 77, 67, 19, 102, 46, 13, 108, 107, 109, 72, 71, 73, 23, 22, 25, 57, 48, 216, 155, 29, 24, 101, 35, 113, 115, 36, 37, 114, 110, 2, 14, 6, 16, 15, 17, 18, 74, 31, 30, 76, 12, 75, 8, 11, 5, 7, 99, 98, 100, 39, 38, 33, 32, 97, 96, 49, 44, 34, 50, 156, 26, 157, 42, 41, 43, 4, 28, 27, 9, 40, 21)
rx <- reorder(dd, y, agglo.FUN=mean)
order.rx <- order.dendrogram(rx)
write(order.rx, file="order_hosts_rx.txt", sep="\t")
write(labels(rx), file="labels_order_hosts_rx.txt", sep="\t")

X11()
par(cex=0.5)
plot(rx, main="Dendrogram of Syn9 genes")
```

I guess it has something to do with the heights of the leaves but I just want to flip the dendrogram...

Thanks in advance!

Miguel

Comment: Maybe `rev(dd)`? `rev.dendrogram` simply returns the dendrogram with reversed nodes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `rev(dd)`; `rev.dendrogram` simply returns the dendrogram with reversed nodes:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
dd <- as.dendrogram(hc)

plot(dd)
```

[image: dendrogram]

```
plot(rev(dd))
```

[image: reversed dendrogram]